# Automatic completion when unique (Emacs auto-complete)

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

How to code auto-complete to immediately trigger when there is only one unique option?
(or, when there are several options, but they all have the same base)

```
(eval-exp_[point-is-here]_)
```

Autocomplete offers:

```
(eval-expression
(eval-expression-print-format)
```

Now when it hits a unique option, wouldn't it be great if it would just immediately complete to `(eval-expression`, and then if we would type `"-"` that it would immediately choose print-format?

Even if there would be then 2 options, you can see in the following example that you would only need `"-p"` to complete:

```
(eval-expression-print-format)
(eval-expression-something-else)
```

Is this behavior possible in Emacs?

Comment: I've seen this kind of completion called "lightning completion" and there was a package under this name for Emacs's minibuffer completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It realizes required behavior:

```
(defadvice ac-inline-show (after eab-ac-expand activate)
  (if (> (length ac-candidates) 1)
      (let ((ac-common-part (try-completion ac-prefix ac-candidates)))
        (ac-expand-common))
    (progn
      (ac-expand-string ac-common-part)
      (ac-inline-hide)))
  (setq eab-last-selected-candidate ac-selected-candidate))
```

For deactivate:

```
(ad-remove-advice 'ac-inline-show 'after 'eab-ac-expand)
(ad-deactivate 'ac-inline-show)
```

EDIT:

I experimented with workflow and found one way to cancel miswritings. As an example you prints `lam` and it is expanded as `lambda` but you adds extra `bd` accidentally and gets `lambdabd`. So I setup

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<tab>") '(lambda () (interactive) (flet ((ac-candidates () `(,eab-last-selected-candidate))) (ac-fuzzy-complete)) (ac-expand)))
```

and use it: `lambdabd` becomes `lambda` and you can continue as usual.

EDIT2:

There was one downside of the solution: "it slows down a bit when it does the fuzzy". It is fixed by narrowing `ac-candidates` to `eab-last-selected-candidate` for `ac-fuzzy-complete`. Now it's fast!

Comment: I would like to try to build in a really short "block" for overtyping the characters, that is, holding back characters that are contained in that part, do you think it's possible? Also, what do you mean with "your environment", do you mean for using this example, or what you'd normally use?

Comment: To clarify, in the example, (eval-e) triggers to eval-expression (well done!), would it be possible to block 'xpr' typing immediately after?

Comment: Yes, it was for using this example. I had some problems with `(setq ac-sources '(ac-source-words-in-buffer ac-source-symbols))`. Now it doesn't matter. I don't think that such blocking `'xpr'` typing for hypothetical example with two functions `eval-expr` and `eval-exprxpr` is a normal behavior.

Comment: Well, I meant that it takes time to see that it completes, usually it completes now, while I'm still typing those 3 characters. So what I'm saying is that I end up with eval-expressionxpr instead of eval-expression (since I type those). It would be great if we could block the continuation after it completes, and ONLY accept other letters than "xpr" (maybe just "xp", but this requires testing). Would you have an idea?

Comment: I think such misbehavior with an extra wrong keystroke should be resolved in general by function `ac-fuzzy-complete`, see the example.

Comment: Oh man, this is really great. I would really advise others to +1 this answer, since this is more than initially asked for. It has only 2 downsides: on my pc it slows down a bit when it does the fuzzy (I tried to automatically fuzzy complete afterwards, bound to SPC, while also inserting a space afterwards). Also, please try to type (beginning-of-line) and then fuzzy complete it: it will change to (beginning-of-buffer). How is that possible?

Comment: This is because of `(ac-expand)` after `(ac-fuzzy-complete)` works like `ac-next` in case of string without misprint. I use such function only if there is a misprint. If you try to apply it to correct string, like `beginning-of-line`, you get next candidate from list.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only few candidates, you can choose each of them by `M-1`, `M-2`, etc. It works fine for 2-7 candidates (compare with keystroke `-p` in your example). You can doen't allow situation with single candidate - use `M-<number>` earlier, when there are still few candidates.

`M-<number>` is keybind for function `ac-complete-<number>`.

Also, function `ac-isearch` (`C-s`) is useful. At the beginning `eva_[point]_` you can search string `fo` or `pr` by pressing `C-s` and then choose from the narrowed list.

Comment: I am aware of the M-1 through M-9 keys, but I do not want to have to count which option to select.

Comment: I agree with you. I would rather use some visual thing like `ace-jump`. And it would be nice use `ido-mode` with `ido-enable-flex-matching` for narrowing candidates. But nobody doesn't cross them with auto-complete yet. ) Also, in your example: if string `expression` completes immediately then how I can cancel it in case of misprint? I have to cancel completed wrong string. It would be annoying. I thing `ac-inline`, which is showed "silently", is a good compromise.

Comment: Miswritings would not have a completion? If you complete something you did not want, you can C-backspace it backwards, and just quickly write the what you meant. I am pretty sure it will pay off in the long run. Don't forget that we are talking only about unique ones that get instantly completed.